# Exponential moving average (EMA) with different number of observations per day but equally weighted observations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` `df1` with observations according to one specific `ID`. The number of observations per `ID` varies over time. For each `ID`, I try to calculate an exponential moving average (EMA) over 3 days. Each observation should be weighted equally within a rolling window of 3 days, regardless of the number of observations on a specific date.

```
df1:
            ID   Value
Date        
2022-01-01  ID1  1
2022-01-01  ID2  0
2022-01-01  ID3  -1
2022-01-02  ID1  1
2022-01-02  ID3  0
2022-01-03  ID1  -1
2022-01-03  ID1  1
2022-01-04  ID1  0
2022-01-04  ID1  1
2022-01-04  ID2  1
2022-01-04  ID3  -1
2022-01-06  ID2  1
2022-01-06  ID2  1
2022-01-06  ID3  -1
```

So far I constructed a simple moving average (SMA) by creating a `pivot` table with the `sum` and `count` of the values per `ID` on each date.

```
pivot:
            sum         count
ID          ID1 ID2 ID3 ID1 ID2 ID3
Date                        
2022-01-01  1   0   -1  1   1   1
2022-01-02  1   0   0   1   0   1
2022-01-03  0   0   0   2   0   0
2022-01-04  1   1   -1  2   1   1
2022-01-06  0   2   -1  0   2   1
```

Then I took the rolling sum over 3 days of the values and divided it by the number of observations and created SMA:

```
SMA:

ID          ID1   ID2   ID3
Date            
2022-01-01  NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-01-02  NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-01-03  0.50  0.0   -0.5
2022-01-04  0.40  1.0   -0.5
2022-01-06  0.25  1.0   -1.0
```

Is there a similar approach for the EMA, so that I exponentially weight each observation over the period regardless of the number of observations on the days?

Thanks a lot and best regards!

For reproducability:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-06', '2022-01-06', '2022-01-06'],
    'ID':['ID1', 'ID2','ID3', 'ID1', 'ID3', 'ID1', 'ID1', 'ID1', 'ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID2', 'ID2', 'ID3'], 
    'Value':[1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1]}) 
df1 = df1.set_index('Date')

pivot = df1.explode('ID').pivot_table(
    index='Date', columns='ID', values='Value', fill_value=0, aggfunc=['sum', 'count'])

SMA = pivot.rolling(3).sum().xs('sum', axis=1, level=0).div(RollingSum.xs('count', axis=1, level=0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, as I am new, I do not have the option to leave a comment. But, you can try pandas `.emw` similar to SMA right?
`pivot.ewm(span=3, min_periods=3).mean()`.

I'm not exactly sure what `RollingSum` does in your code; but try this:

```
EMA = pivot.ewm(span=3, min_periods=3).mean().div(RollingSum.xs('count', axis=1, level=0))
```